# pyinstaller exception after build the application due to an unknow file

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, spyder

I created an python programme with this imports :

```
import requests
import os
import json
from wrpy import get_available_dicts,WordReference
import deepl 
import win32com.client as win32
import ast
import time
import random
```

I installed pyinstaller with the command :
`conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller`

But when i run the application once build, i get this error :

```
PS D:\Folders\Code\Python\English\English application\dist> .\english.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "english.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "wrpy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "wrpy\core.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\base.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\device.py", line 6, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\esto5\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI96602\\user_agent\\data/smartphone_dev_id.json'
[14468] Failed to execute script 'english' due to unhandled exception!
```

This exception come before run any of my code.

I don't have the folder _MEI96602 at this location. and not smartphone_dev_id in my computer.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your script is trying to access a json file. Pyinstaller won’t include such files unless you explicitly tell it to.

Use —-add-data src dst when calling pyinstaller

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: The file that it his looking for don't exist in my computer, i don't know why it ask for it. All work well when i run the .py.

Comment: according to the error it's part of wrpy. Look in user_agent\device.py